# What deck are Will Riker's living quarters on?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, uss-enterprise, riker

According to [this Wiki](http://greatestgen.wikia.com/wiki/Riker%27s_Quarters), Riker has two quarters. To clear up any confusion that may arise in advance, I am talking about his main living quarters - not the ones he takes his concubines to. I can't remember which deck his quarters are on at the moment.

**Bonus:** Is there a reference or list available that has the characters names and which deck(s) their quarters are on? I'm writing a fan fiction (don't judge me!) and this would be very helpful!

Comment: You may wish to note that that wiki is very firmly tongue-in-cheek non-canon.

Comment: Concubines 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [StarTrek.com](http://www.startrek.com/database_article/riker-william) website lists William Riker's quarters as being on

> **Room 0912, first Deck 8, then Deck 9**
>
> <sub><sup>[William Riker - Startrek.com](http://www.startrek.com/database_article/riker-william)</sup></sub>

Presumably the Deck 8 reference relates to the Enteprise-D, Deck 9 to the
slightly larger Enterprise-E.

---

For the record, other crew members are said to be at the following locations;

- Captain Picard - **Deck 9, Room 3601**
- Worf - **Deck 7, Sect. 25B**
- Beverly Crusher - **Deck 8/Room 2133**
- Data - **Deck 2/Room 3653**
- Counsellor Troi - **Deck 9/Room 0910**

Comment: Hm — looks like Riker’s quarters are pretty close to Troi’s.

Comment: @PaulDWaite - In case he needs a late night counselling session, presumably.